# Is there a way to use/recompile libgio-2.0 on machine with libc-2.5?

Tags: linux, libraries, scientific-linux, binary, dependencies

I have a program (JavaFX 2, namely), and one of its binaries (libglass.so) requires `libgio-2.0.so.0`. The problem is, the system, on which I need to run the app, is quite old and mostly out of my control (thus I can't update it).

I tired copying `libgio` from my machine there, but only to find that `libgio` requires `GLIBC_2.9` - and target machine only has libc-2.5.

Is there a way to work around this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious solution is to build glibc 2.9, copy that over as well (do not overwrite the existing one!), then run javafx with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/old/glibc/libraries:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"` prepended. Alternatively put that path at the end of /etc/ld.so.conf and rerun `ldconfig`.

Comment: Hm. That machine already has glibc 2.5, so why should I rebuild it?

Comment: I tried copying over libc 2.12 (and ld-linux), but got only as far as segfault.

Comment: oops, I meant 2.9, fixing. It needs to be the same glibc the package was built against to be completely safe.

Comment: There is this question - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2717/running-a-statically-linked-binary-with-a-different-glibc?rq=1, and it is stated there that just recompiling glibc wouldn't help :(

Comment: but libglass and libgio are not statically linked or their names wouldn't end in ".so".

Comment: Yes, but as it was stated in that post, libc looks for loaders in standard locations. Wouldn't 2.9 segfault when trying to use 2.5 loader?

Comment: Forgive my questions, I'm just very new to all that static/dynamic libraries stuff :)

Comment: I'm not sure. There may be extra environment variables dictating it, the way it was built or it may really be hardcoded. The bulletproof solution is to run everything in a separate chroot, but since javafx is a gui application it would not be simple to use. :(